# Why isn't CSS visibility working?

Tags: css, visibility

I added a "spoiler" class in CSS to use for, well, spoilers. Text is normally invisible but appears when the mouse hovers over it to reveal the spoiler to whoever wants to read it.

```
.spoiler{
    visibility:hidden;

}
.spoiler:hover {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Should be simple, but for some reason this doesn't work. The text remains invisible even when I point the mouse on it. Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You cannot hover over a hidden element. One solution is to nest the element inside another container:

CSS:

```
.spoiler span {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.spoiler:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
Spoiler: <span class="spoiler"><span>E.T. phones home.</span></span>
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/DBXuv/

### Update

On Chrome, the following can be added:

```
.spoiler {
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DBXuv/148/

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: This was just a demonstration of the concept. Based on the target browsers, a more suitable container such as a dummy `<a>` can be picked.

Comment: I knew this had to be out there.  Was not disappointed.  Thanks

Comment: @tostinni - nasty chrome bug, by the looks of it: you can avoid it by adding `.spoiler {outline:1px solid transparent;}` or pretty much anything that would make the element "render" even if all rendered pixels happen to be transparent.

Comment: Thanks @EamonNerbonne. Update: http://jsfiddle.net/DBXuv/148/ (And BTW, wow. People have done 147 experiments over this.)

Comment: Note that `visibility` may render poorly in some cases.  In particular, if you have several divs with hidden content, and this content contains images, when you hover one div then another the newly displayed div may appear quicker than the images of the previous div would disappear (tested on several browsers).  In such cases Jon Ander's solution below seems much more efficient.

Answer (score 32):

It works not only for text

```
.spoiler {
    opacity:0;
}
.spoiler:hover {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out .0s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out .0s;
}
```

Comment: Neat solution.  Contrarily to other answers (except the accepted one, which has some drawbacks, see comments), it does work not only for text but also for anything else.

Comment: Nice. Works also when `position: absolute`.

Comment: Do you mean it only works for text ?

Comment: It works for all kinds of HTML elements basically

Answer (score 2):

When the text is invisible, it practically does not occupy space, so it's practically imposible to trigger an hover event.

You should try another approach, for example, changing the font color:

```
.spoiler{
    color:white;

}
.spoiler:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: The visibility property does take up space, it's the display property that does not.

Comment: Isn't this the way phpBB implement their [spoiler] tags?

Answer (score 1):

`:hover` pseudo class is only for `a` tags according to the CSS spec.  User agents are not required to support `:hover` for non-anchor tags [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act).

If you want to use CSS to make visible your spoiler text you will need to place `<a>` tags around your spoiler content.  This of course will mean that the mouse would turn into a pointer, but you can suppress this by adding `cursor: none;`.

Comment: I just saw your comment to my answer.  And yeah @Ates Goral is correct.  This is actually how many CSS menus work by the way.

Comment: :hover is valid for all elements. According to the spec you linked, some User agents might not handle it, but it makes no mention of specific elements :hover does or doesn't work with.

Comment: What the spec incidentally means is probably things like touch-screens, where the concept of hover is dubious at best.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not working the try

```css
.spoiler span {
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height:20px;
}

.spoiler:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score -8):

Try

```
.spoiler{
    display:none;

}
.spoiler:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This would be similar to the problem in the initial question (in that you can't hover over the spoiler block), except marginally *worse*, in that a `display:none` element doesn't occupy any space in box model at all, so *definitely* could never be hovered over.