# How to show/hide delete button with CSS?

Tags: css

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="Xbutton">
    </div>
</div>

/*THE CSS*/
.Xbutton { display:none; }
.Xbutton:hover { display:inline-block; }
```

How can I set "display:inline-block" to "Xbutton" when someone hovers "container" in CSS only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="Xbutton">
    </div>
</div>

/*THE CSS*/
.Xbutton { display:none; }
.container:hover .Xbutton { display:inline-block; }
```

This solution will not work in IE6, and might be buggy in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot hover an element that isn't showing.

Check [Why isn't css visibility working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working)