# CSS hover not working on hidden elements?

Tags: css, image, styling

I am not sure what is going on here but the rollover is not working correctly and I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using very basic and simple css:

```
open{visibility:hidden;}
open:hover{visibility:visible;}
```

http://www.ubhape2.com/messages/files/chameleon/ is the page i am working on

Please forgive the god awful code. I am using it as a simple and quick method. Just need the roll over to work and I am good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you can't hover over a hidden element (see [Why isn't CSS visibility working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working)).

The solution posted there is also a good alternative for this issue. There are lots of other ways to do it though, such as a div with an image in the background, like:

```
<style> 
div.open { background: none; width: 137px; height: 49px; }
div.open:hover { background:url('images/chameleon_10.gif'); }
</style>
<div class="open"></div>
```

Or if you need to use an image, you can use image sprites (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)

See basic [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/ML4Kn/).

Comment: Thanks got it working by using the method in the link you provided. =>

Answer (score 36):

You can use the `opacity` property:

```
.open{opacity:0;}
.open:hover{opacity:1;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code, should work fine

```
a.open{visibility:hidden;} 
a.open:hover{visibility:visible;}


<a class="open" href="">Open</a>
```

Comment: -1 his code references `#open{visibility...` in the CSS and `<img id="open"...` in the DOM

Comment: write "a.open" instead "a .open"

Comment: Alien I have that as my code originally and it does not work. That is why I am confused.