# CSS image hover problem in Chrome and IE

Tags: css, hover

I have problem of display an hidden image when mouse over to an image by using CSS hover in Chrome and IE, but is working fine in Firefox.
Here is my link: *https://www.solarisdutamas.com/fb/Elvieloon/welcome1.php*

Here is my coding:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css-hover.css" />
</head>
<title>Elvie Loon</title>
<meta content="Professional Makeup Artist and Hair Stylist" name="description">
<style type="text/css">
.over .pic1 {
   display:none;
   visibility:hidden;
}
.over:hover .pic1 {
   display:inline;
   visibility:visible;
   position:absolute;
   top:250px;
   left:100px;
   z-index:11;
}
</style>
<body style="margin: 0px; width: 520px;">
<img src="landing-page.jpg" usemap ="#fly1map" />

<a class="over"> 
  <map name="fly1map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="387,339,433,365,416,376,425,395,371,393,391,369,387,339" href="">
  </map> 
  <img src="pic-1.png" class="pic1">  
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of visibility try this...

```
#something:hover
{
    opacity:1; //100% opacity
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

#something 
{
    opacity:0; //0% opacity
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

P.s Both lines inside the statement do the same thing, the bottom filter, is just IE's way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I tried your method but the same problem still exist. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't hover over a hidden element (see [Why isn't CSS visibility working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working)).

Two ideas...

**1.** You could use a technique with two images. In addition to your image, create a transparent image of the same size. Then flip them on the mouse hover.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .flipimage { border:solid 1px pink; height:65px; width:65px; background-image:url("blank.jpg"); } 
    .flipimage:hover { border:solid 1px pink; height:65px; width:65px; background-image:url("truck.jpg"); } 
</style>


<body style="margin: 0px; width: 520px;">

    <div class="flipimage"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**2.** This approach takes some additional markup, but essentially it places a `<div>` above the image. When you hover over the `<div>` it is moved below the image using the `z-index`.

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
    .placeholder{ background-color:pink; height:64px; width:64px; position:absolute; z-index:99; }
    .placeholder:hover { z-index:-1; }
    .over { position:absolute; z-index:1;}
   </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; width: 520px;">

    <div>
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
        <a class="over"><img src="vcard.jpg" class="pic1"></a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug with Chrome and IE8 related to :hover and z-index on absolute positioned elements.

[Chrome: Issue 83533](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83533)