# Hide & show image when mouse over

Tags: asp.net

I am working on pictures inside ASP.net (VB)
and try to make this picture hide when the mouse over and show if it mouse out
How can I do this without using script or jQuery ?

help me please

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Javascript or CSS.

For example, to use CSS:

```
<img class="hideshowimage" ... />
```

and in your CSS

```
.hideshowimage:hover { visibility:hidden; }
```

Comment: how about the opposite if i want the image show when mouse over and hide when mouse out?

Comment: Updated answer. I also changed it from `display` to `visibility` as I assume you want to maintain the layout, even when the image is hidden.

Comment: i used your code it work but the image shake when mouse over i don't know whats the problem?

Comment: Did you use the old `display` code or the new `visibility` one?

Comment: when i used the new visibility  no shake appear , but the image is hidden all time even the mouse over

Comment: Ah yes, the hover method won't work over visibility. Try the method suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working The shaking is caused because `display` doesn't maintain the layout whereas visibility does.

Comment: <asp:Image  class="spoiler" ID="riyadh" runat="server"  ImageUrl="riyadh.png" 
            style="position: relative; top: 14px; left: -326px" />      ,,,,,,,,,,and in css : }
.spoiler span {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.spoiler:hover  {
    visibility: visible;
} ,,, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: +1 - these pseudoselectors (is that what they're called??) aren't used nearly enough.  Much cleaner than JavaScript / jQuery solutions.  Assuming of course not supporting old IE is an option...sigh

Comment: @Beso You need to add the span element  <span class="spoiler"><asp:Image  ID="riyadh" runat="server" ImageUrl="riyadh.png" style="position: relative; top: 14px; left: -326px" /></span>