# H1 flickering instead of hiding

Tags: html, css

So I was trying to build a hexagonal layout, I followed a code pen tutorial and it works great. However when I put a H1 in the div, I want it to disappear on hover, it does this but only every now and again. Most of the time it flickers.

JS fiddle link below

http://jsfiddle.net/bcsz6whz/

HTML and CSS Code

```
<section id="lab">

    <article>

        <div class="lab_item">    
        <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/320);">

                  <h1 class="hoverheading">Test<br />Test</h1>

                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          <div class="lab_item">
          <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/320);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
 <div class="lab_item">
          <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/310);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
 <div class="lab_item">
          <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
              <div class="lab_item">        
        <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          <div class="lab_item">
          <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/400);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          <div class="lab_item">
          <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          <div class="lab_item">
          <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/600);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          <div class="lab_item">
          <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/700/700);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          <div class="lab_item">
          <div class="hexagon hexagon2">
            <div class="hexagon-in1">
                <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/250/300);">                
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>




  </article>
</section>

<style type="text/css">

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  /*display: block;*/
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#lab {
  /*width: 1000px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;

  /*-webkit-transition: all ease 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all ease 500ms;
  -o-transition: all ease 500ms;
  -ms-transition: all ease 500ms;
  transition: all ease 500ms;*/
}

h1 {
  /*font-family: bebas_neueregular ,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  padding: 0.2em 0 0.2em 0.2em;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: 0 0.06em 0 #424242;*/
  position: relative;

}

#lab h1 {
}

#lab h1:hover {
visibility: hidden;
}

#lab .hoverheading {
  top: 140px;
    /* left: 11px; */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;

}

#lab .hoverheading:hover{
  visibility: hidden;
}

/*.beaker {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(#424242 0px 1px 0px);
  border-bottom: 2em solid #FFF;
  border-left: 1em solid transparent;
  border-right: 1em solid transparent;
  border-radius: .5em;
  height: 0;
  width: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.7em;
  bottom: 22%;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

.beaker::before {
  border-left: .25em solid #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em;
  border-right: .25em solid #FFF;
  content: '';
  height: .25em;
  left: -.25em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  width: 1em;
}

.beaker::after {
  border-left: .25em solid #FFF;
  border-right: .25em solid #FFF;
  content: '';
  height: 1em;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  width: .5em;
}*/

.sectionheader {
  position: relative;
}

.lab_item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 230px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hexagon2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  top: -85px;
}

.hexagon {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hexagon-in1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon-in2 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(253, 242, 0, 1.00);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(253, 242, 0, 1.00);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;

  -webkit-background-size: 125%;
  -moz-background-size: 125%;
  background-size: 125%;
  visibility: visible;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hexagon-in2:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px #B0DAD4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px #B0DAD4;
}

#lab article {
  padding-top: 1em;
  width: 820px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(7n-2) {
  margin-left: 101px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(n+5) {
  margin-top: -55px;
}

@media (max-width: 1015px) {
  #lab {
  width: 100%;
}

}

@media (max-width: 820px) {
  .lab_item:nth-child(5n-1) {
  margin-left: 102px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(n+4) {
  margin-top: -62px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(7n-2) {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(n+5) {
  margin-top: -56px;
}

#lab article {
  width: 610px;
}

}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  #lab article {
  width: 405px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(5n-1) {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-left: 102px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(n+3) {
  margin-top: -56px;
}

}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  #lab article {
  width: 300px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: 102px;
}

.lab_item:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-top: -56px;
}

}

</style>
```

I can't figure out it flickers and doesn't hide correctly

Could you point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: you assigned twice 'visibility: hidden; ' to have this affect, this is your right direction.. if not successful please @me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working) answer, `:hover` does not work if `visibility` is set to `hidden`. An alternative would be to change `visiblity:hidden` to `opacity:0`, where `:hover` does continue to work. The reason it flickered before was this:

1. You hovered over it, it disappeared
2. Now that it has disappeared, it's not hovered over anymore, and reappears
3. Repeat from 1

Here is a corrected version that hides the title when you hover over it with `opacity:0`:

http://jsfiddle.net/bcsz6whz/1/

Comment: That was quick haha. But isn't the h1 element supposed to disappear when the user hovers on the entire container and not only on the text?

Comment: No clue. The OP set it to disappear on heading hover so I stayed with that. I do have the suspicion that you might be right though. On that note, in your solution your h1 element disappears even when the mouse is not over the hexagon sometimes. :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **working solution**:

[http://jsfiddle.net/bcsz6whz/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/bcsz6whz/2/)

Changed `visibility:hidden;` to an opacity setting. I also made it trigger when you hover on its parent element `.hexagon` to get the effect not only when you hover on the text.

```
.hexagon:hover h1{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Explanation: I think when you hover over your h1 tag with `visibility:hidden;` it becomes "unhoverable", so the effect wears off.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding a jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#certain-hexagonId").hover(function() {
        $("#the-hexagones-h1-ID").hide();
    )};
});
```

hope this helps!

You can also use (for CSS) `opacity: 0` instead of `visibility: hidden`

Comment: I have to say it is best to avoid javascript solutions wherever possible as there are usually significant performance hits when using JS (and especially jQuery). On another note, changing `visibility:hidden` to `display:none` doesn't fix the issue.