# :hover on image shows other images

Tags: html, css, hover

I am try to create `:hover` on images and make them show other images like menu to other pages. I have tried this code but when mouse is over sub-menu it opens instead to open just over main menu. I try to achieve something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iya0oqKlBns

I used this code:

```css
img{
width:150px;
}
body {
    background:transparent;
}

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:transparent;
}

.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:transparent;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:transparent;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:transparent;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:110%;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 1.15s;

    background:transparent;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:transparent;
}

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:transparent;
}

.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:transparent;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:transparent;
}
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}
/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:transparent;
}
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.sub-menu {

    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:-60%;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 1.15s;

    background:transparent;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">

            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">

            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect from the video can be achieved with a lot of css using the Hover pseudo class, transitions and tranforms and absolute positioning.

[Check out my pen here](http://codepen.io/MBarnes/pen/KrQqYp)

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li>
      <!--Wrap content in div -->
      <div class="big-icon bi1">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

        <!--Hidden menu here -->
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi2">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi3">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi4">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi5">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi6">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi7">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi8">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi9">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi10">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi11">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="big-icon bi12">
        <a href="#" class="big-img"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LIFESTYLE.png"><span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/lepota.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/svadba.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/nocni-zivot.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://tronline.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/MUZIKA.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>    
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
img{
width:150px;
}
body {
    background:transparent;
}

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/*----- General Style -----*/
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}

.main-menu li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.big-icon {
  position: relative;
}

.big-icon:hover .big-img {
  opacity: .8;
}


/*----- Small Arrow Position and Transform -----*/
.big-icon span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform .3s, opacity .3s;
  color: black;
}

.big-icon:hover span {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

/*----- Positioning/hiding sub Menu -----*/

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -85px;
}

.sub-menu img {
  width: 75px;
}

.sub-menu li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 122px;
  opacity: 0;
}

/*----- Sub Menu - Transistions and Transforms -----*/

.sub-menu li:first-child {
  transition: top .3s, left .3s, opacity .3s;
}

.sub-menu li:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition: top .3s .3s, left .3s .3s, opacity .3s .3s;
}

.sub-menu li:nth-of-type(3) {
  transition: top .3s .6s, left .3s .6s, opacity .3s .6s;
}

.sub-menu li:last-child {
  transition: top .3s .9s, left .3s .9s, opacity .3s .9s;
}

.bi1:hover li:first-child,
.bi5:hover li:first-child,
.bi9:hover li:first-child {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi1:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi5:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi9:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 0px;
  top: 80px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi1:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi5:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi9:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 0px;
  top: 160px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi1:hover li:last-child,
.bi5:hover li:last-child,
.bi9:hover li:last-child {
  left: 0px;
  top: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi2:hover li:first-child,
.bi6:hover li:first-child,
.bi10:hover li:first-child {
  left: -150px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi2:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi6:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi10:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: -150px;
  top: 80px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi2:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi6:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi10:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: -150px;
  top: 160px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi2:hover li:last-child, 
.bi6:hover li:last-child,
.bi10:hover li:last-child {
  left: -150px;
  top: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi3:hover li:first-child,
.bi7:hover li:first-child,
.bi11:hover li:first-child {
  left: -305px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi3:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi7:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi11:hover li:nth-of-type(2){
  left: -305px;
  top: 80px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi3:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi7:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi11:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: -305px;
  top: 160px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi3:hover li:last-child,
.bi7:hover li:last-child,
.bi11:hover li:last-child {
  left: -305px;
  top: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi4:hover li:first-child,
.bi8:hover li:first-child,
.bi12:hover li:first-child {
  left: -460px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi4:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi8:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi12:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: -460px;
  top: 80px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi4:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi8:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi12:hover li:nth-of-type(3){
  left: -460px;
  top: 160px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi4:hover li:last-child,
.bi8:hover li:last-child,
.bi12:hover li:last-child {
  left: -460px;
  top: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi4:hover li:first-child,
.bi8:hover li:first-child,
.bi12:hover li:first-child {
  left: -460px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bi5:hover li:first-child,
.bi6:hover li:first-child,
.bi7:hover li:first-child,
.bi8:hover li:first-child {
  top: -153px;
}

.bi5:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi6:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi7:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi8:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: -73px;
}

.bi5:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi6:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi7:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi8:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 8px;
}

.bi5:hover li:last-child,
.bi6:hover li:last-child,
.bi7:hover li:last-child,
.bi8:hover li:last-child {
  top: 89px;
}

.bi9:hover li:first-child,
.bi10:hover li:first-child,
.bi11:hover li:first-child,
.bi12:hover li:first-child {
  top: -307px;
}

.bi9:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi10:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi11:hover li:nth-of-type(2),
.bi12:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: -225px;
}

.bi9:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi10:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi11:hover li:nth-of-type(3),
.bi12:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: -142px;
}

.bi9:hover li:last-child,
.bi10:hover li:last-child,
.bi11:hover li:last-child,
.bi12:hover li:last-child {
  top: -60px;
}
```

I'd like to note:

1) Using hover doesn't really work for this menu because if you mouse over the main img's on the right you can't get to the sub-menu in time to select an item. Really you need JavaScript or jQuery to add a click event to show the sub menu.

2) It will take a lot of work to make it fully responsive with smaller width screens - I'd only display menu on large screens because of absolute positioning.

3) This has a lot of repeated code, would be much better to have JavaScript/PHP to automate code entry

Please note - I have not included vendor-prefixes. CSS properties such as flex-box, transition, transform etc. would need prefixes.

Comment: Great Matthew, yes I have seen that there is trouble with responsive design, but mu knowledge of JavaScript is very humble. Manage to copy your code and to get this but where to put z-index to , that the submenu item remains while on the top other other main menu. Just copied your css. My pen is here `http://codepen.io/milangru/pen/EyEpEV`

Comment: I have manage to do that with the Jquery, but when the mouse goes hover sub-menu it disappears . How to leave it active when the mouse is hover sub-menu? PS how to hide sub-menu with jquery and not with css? http://codepen.io/milangru/pen/AXapad

Answer (score 0):

Although you're currently using CSS to visually 'hide' your sub-menus, you're not writing in any styles that remove their ability to be `:hover`ed by the mouse when inactive. Without this, they're simply still able to trigger the transition on their own without the main menu's icon.

**In other words, something like the `display` or `visibility` properties removes the element's ability to trigger `:hover` events with the mouse cursor.**

Here's a codepen for you to check out:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBRzZN

From W3C Spec:

### Interpolation

Visiblity values are interpolable between visible and not-visible. One of the start or ending values must therefore be visible or no interpolation can happen. If one of the values is visible, interpolated as a discrete step where values of the timing function between 0 and 1 map to visible and other values of the timing function (which occur only at the start/end of the transition or as a result of cubic-bezier() functions with y values outside of [0, 1]) map to the closer endpoint.

Further reading:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animtype-visibility
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929336/6177319