# nesting multiple classes using sass

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to nest multiple class using sass. I want to use hover to show a button. My scss is as follows:

```
.item{
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-indent: 50px;
  height: 81%;
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: green;

   .Button{
      visibility: hidden;

        &:hover{
          visibility: visible;
        }
    }
}
```

this is shown in css as :

```
.item {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-indent: 50px;
  height: 81%;
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: green; }

  .item .Button {
    visibility: hidden; }

    .item .Button:hover {
      visibility: visible; }
```

The hover property is not working here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the button is already hidden, I would put the visible property on the item:hover instead.

How the SCSS should look:

```
.item {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-indent: 50px;
  height: 81%;
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: green;

  .Button {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  &:hover .Button {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```css
.item {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-indent: 50px;
  height: 81%;
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: green; 
}

.item .Button {
  visibility: hidden; 
}

.item:hover .Button {
  visibility: visible; 
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  Hover Item Class
  <button class="Button">button shows</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I know how css should look, but point is how to write .scss for it

Comment: Please see the top part of the answer

Comment: oh yes! got it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.item{
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-indent: 50px;
  height: 81%;
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: green;

  &:hover {
    .btn {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
  .btn{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```