# Button Visibility Toggle Not Functioning jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to code a number of buttons that are invisible and **only appears when you hover** above them. When the mouse leaves where the button is, it should go back to being hidden. All the methods I tried--which I listed below--does not seem to work. First I tried to change the css property which fails, then the toggling of a class does not work either.

***EDIT**, now could I allow user to click on a button once they hover above them, then the button will be **selected and remain visible**?

html

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="overlay">
        <form action="">
          <input type="button" name="b" id="w1" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="w2" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="w3" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="w4" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="b1" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="b2" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="b3" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="b4" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="r1" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="r2" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="r3" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="r4" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="g1" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="g2" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="g3" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" name="b" id="g4" class="data hidden"/>
          <input type="button" id="continue" value="continue" class="control"/>
          <input type="button" id="replay" value="replay" class="control"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="base">
        <img id="myImage">
      </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
#base {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 400px;
}  
.data {

}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hidden:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Cant  trigger the event on invisible element

Comment: Could you explain further?

Comment: hidden elements are not "computed" by processor, use another way to hide (opacity/resize/overlay perhaps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't CSS visibility working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working)

Comment: ahh I see, I didn't see that thread when I searched on StackOverFlow; thought it was a Jquery/Javascript issue.

Comment: @AlexKer see my answer. i was explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `opacity` instead?

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

#base {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 400px;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hidden:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="overlay">
    <form action="">
      <input type="button" name="b" id="w1" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="w2" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="w3" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="w4" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="b1" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="b2" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="b3" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="b4" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="r1" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="r2" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="r3" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="r4" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="g1" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="g2" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="g3" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" name="b" id="g4" class="data hidden" />
      <input type="button" id="continue" value="continue" class="control" />
      <input type="button" id="replay" value="replay" class="control" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="base">
    <img id="myImage">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with jQuery/javascript?

Comment: @AlexKer using `visibility` property? or using `opacity`?

Comment: Does that make a difference? And my question was that is there a way to accomplish it using Jquery and Javascript

Comment: @AlexKer In fairness, you tagged your question `CSS` and said that it was an approach you tried and failed. Which property you use does make a difference, see this question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden

Comment: Could you see my updated question. I forgot to include one feature.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem .`invisible` could't trigger any event .see the snippet.You could use `opacity` or `width` and `height` 0 .Try out the click but no element is there to click

**Error**

```css
a{
color:red;
display:none;
}
a:hover{
color:green
}
```

```html
<a class="p" onclick="console.log('ssx')">assdsds</a>
```

Comment: could you see my updated question. I edited my post.