# How do I make a link become visible when my mouse is over it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a link to be hidden at first, and when the cursor is over the link, it appears. So far I have:

HTML:

```
<a id ="contact" style="visibility:'hidden';">Contact Me</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var link = document.getElementById("contact");
function visible() { link.style.visibility = 'visible';}
function hidden() { link.style.visibility = 'hidden';}
link.onmouseover = visible;
link.onmouseout = hidden;
```

The onmouseout part works fine when the link is visible, but whenever I put my mouse over the link again, it doesn't become visible again. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: How can a user possibly know to hover over something they can't see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's usually done with CSS:

```css
#contact       { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s; }
#contact:hover { opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s; }
```

```html
<a id=contact>Contact Me</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Reason: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working)

> You cannot hover over a hidden element.

Please use opacity to hide the link like so.

```js
var link = document.getElementById("contact");
function visible() { link.style.opacity = 1;}
function hidden() { link.style.opacity = 0;}
link.onmouseover = visible;
link.onmouseout = hidden;
```

```html
<a id ="contact" style="opacity:0;">Contact Me</a>
```

Comment: @Andi Did this answer help you? can it be closed?