# Only make a button appear on hover

Tags: javascript, html, angular, sass

Can anyone help me out with something really simple but can't seem to find anywhere. I am using scss right now and I want the button to only display when I hover it. I have it hidden right now and here is the code. I am also using svgs and my button is nested within a block. Thanks guys

```
&__button {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url("../../assets/Icons\ -\ Thin\ Delete.svg") center center no-repeat;
    &:hover {
      background: url("../../assets/Icons\ -\ Thin\ Delete\ On\ Hover.svg") center center no-repeat;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibility: hidden` for default state and `visibility: visible` for hover state.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

However, you have to nest your button inside another div. Hover states don't work when an element is hidden. ([Why isn't CSS visibility working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working))

Example code:

HTML

```
<div class="button-container">
    <button>
        Hover
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button-container button {
    visibility: hidden;
    ...
}

.button-container:hover button {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

or in SCSS

```
.button-container {
    button {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    &:hover {
        button {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope you can translate it into your requirements (SCSS and HTML).

Comment: I guarantee that's right. The way I have this block set up though is much different. I have the button nested already. The hover state works in general. The state that doesn't work at all is making it completely disappear then being able to hover it. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong. It's a extra pain to do with svg because I can do it with images and links just can't figure it out with the layout I have mixed with svg

Comment: Your way also worked. But it broke the functionality. For now I'm using the way below but when this actually gets deployed in a week or two it will probably be changed to this way. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better simply use opacity.

NOTE: Obviously, it's not visible but still affects layout as normal

```
   .button
    {
      opacity:0
    }
    .button:hover
    {
      opacity:1
    }
```

Comment: Yup that worked and the functionality still works how it should. Not sure if that's how I'm going to leave it when it actually gets deployed but for now it has put my mind at ease and works. Thank you so much!