# Showing button after keydown event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show 2 buttons when keydown event is triggered. It's actually for profile page where when any data is edited Then only update or cancel button should appear.but by default these buttons should be not seen.I used js to show the button or trigger a css class whenever the keydown event is triggered but that seems to not work.

```js
let updateBtn = document.getElementbyID('updateBtn');

function showUpdate() {
  updateBtn.classList.add("upBtnPop");

}
```

```css
.upBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(67, 207, 67);
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.upBtn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(142, 168, 39);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.upBtnPop {
  visibility: visible;
}

.cnBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(67, 207, 67);
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cnBtn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(142, 168, 39);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.cnBtnPop {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="userClass" onkeyup="showUpdate();" id="userData" name="name">
  <p>Full Name : <input class="userData" value="<?php echo $ret_data['fullName'] ?>" type="text"></p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="userClass" onkeyup="showUpdate();" id="userData" name="email">
  <p>Email : <input class="userData" value="<?php echo $ret_data['email'] ?>" type="text"></p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="userClass" onkeyup="showUpdate();" id="userData" name="contact">
  <p>Phone : <input class="userData" value="<?php echo $ret_data['contactNum'] ?>" type="text"></p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="userClass" onkeyup="showUpdate();" id="userData" name="password">
  <p>Password : <a href="">Change Password ?</a></p>
</div>
<br>
<button class="upBtn" id="updateBtn">Update</button>
<button class="cnBtn" id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
<a href="logout.php"><button class="logBtn">Log out</button></a>
```

Comment: Please show the css for the `upBtnPop` class; and it'll still have the `upBtn` class [which is hidden] if you don't remove it so the button still might not show, depending on how your stylesheet is arranged. Also, you might want to revise the way the rest of your css is as well - I don't think `:hover` works on hidden elements (see [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working))

Comment: I have edited my code Could you please look into it

Comment: does it still not work for you? when I do type anything into any of the inputs now, the update button shows up. [cancel button still never shows - you don't seem to have called or even defined any function like `showUpdate` for it]

Comment: Check the Console. There will be an error there, because you misspelled `getElementById`.

Comment: What @RickardElimää said, it's probably why it didn't work for you. I corrected it before running but forgot to mention in comment - you should always [check with devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#the_javascript_debugger) first when your code doesn't behave as expected

Comment: Devtools was showing no error console showed me nothing. I will give it a try once more

Comment: It worked guys but however I made too mess for just a small thing so I went to the below answer one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the wrong case for `document.getElementById()`. You typed `document.getElementbyID()`. In addition to this, you should remove the `.upBtnPop` style rule, and instead add a `isHidden` class to the button on load, with a single style rule for that class, hiding the button. Then simply remove the class when the `onKeyUp` event is fired.

Finally, make these slight changes:

- move all of those event declarations to the Javascript, so you can better control them (and you're not repeating yourself).
- move the keyup event listener to the inputs themselves.
- move the name attributes to the inputs and remove the password name attribute.
- remove the ids from the `.userClass` divs. Id names can only be used once per page.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.userData');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    document.getElementById('updateBtn').classList.remove('isHidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.upBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(67, 207, 67);
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.upBtn.isHidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.upBtn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(142, 168, 39);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.cnBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(67, 207, 67);
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cnBtn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(142, 168, 39);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.cnBtnPop {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="userClass">
  <p>Full Name : <input class="userData" value="John Doe" type="text" name="name"></p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="userClass">
  <p>Email : <input class="userData" value="johndoe@yahoo.com" type="text" name="email"></p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="userClass">
  <p>Phone : <input class="userData" value="555-1234" type="text" name="contact"></p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="userClass">
  <p>Password : <a href="">Change Password ?</a></p>
</div>
<br>
<button class="upBtn isHidden" id="updateBtn">Update</button>
<button class="cnBtn" id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
<a href="logout.php"><button class="logBtn">Log out</button></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I went through all of your codes, and it worked. Now I know what I did and also thanks for that last point. Learnt something I am just new to developing. Thanks