# Is there any ways to apply style into an #id selector when the sidebar is hovered?

Tags: css, razor, styling

I am new into CSS and I have a question regarding my CSS styling. I have a code that looks like this:

```
<style>

#span_logout {
display: none;
}

</style>
```

This span has a `id` called "span_logout" was put into a `class` named "sidebar" and it was hidden at the load at the beginning of a page load. I wanted to show the span when the sidebar is hovered but I tried few ways and I dont find any solutions.

I tried adding this as an example but I didn't manage to solve the problem:

```
<style>

#span_logout {
display: none;
}


.sidebar-hovered #span_logout {
display: block !important;
}

</style>
```

Is there any ways to apply style into an #id selector when the sidebar is hovered?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hover over something that is `display: none` and/or has not `visibility`. You should do something like this:

```css
.sidebar-hovered span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.sidebar-hovered:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
Hover: <span id="span_logout" class="sidebar-hovered"><span>Content here</span></span>
```

See: [Why isn't CSS visibility working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929310/why-isnt-css-visibility-working)